# spring-data JpaRepository Optional orElse duplicate entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I got 2 versions of the same code (i assume):

```
Optional<UserHolder> user = userHolderRepository.findOneByUserId(source.getId());
return user.isPresent()
    ? user.get()
    : userHolderRepository.save(new UserHolder(source.getId(), source.getLogin()));
```

and

```
UserHolder userHolder = userHolderRepository
            .findOneByUserId(source.getId())
            .orElse(userHolderRepository.save(new UserHolder(source.getId(), source.getLogin())));

        return userHolder;
```

I also got a `Message` entity with `@ManyToOne` userHolders.

if I call the above code to get a user holder (if exists, or create one instead), the first snippet works well while the second snippet always lead to create a second userHolder with the same id.

i think the code snippets are not behaving identical, but how should I write the `Optional` style code to be exactly the same as the first snippet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the right solution to solve this is

```
UserHolder userHolder = userHolderRepository
            .findOneByUserId(source.getId())
            .orElseGet(() ->userHolderRepository.save(new UserHolder(source.getId(), source.getLogin())));

        return userHolder;
```

because like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget), orElse is always generating the object, even if the `Optional` does contain a value.