# When I need to use Optional.orElseGet() over Optional.orElse()

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I need a clear explanation of this, even though I read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget) on differences but no clear clarity. So can anyone explain to me on this in short with code?

Comment: What is not clear in the accepted answer?

Comment: I not got clear picture with that answer

Comment: Generally you can use one or the other as you like.

Comment: If producing the value to return in the “orElse” case requires some computation, my taste would probably be for `orElseGet()` so that the computation is only performed when needed. If the computation has side effects, you should choose based on whether you want those sideeffects always or only when the object is needed.

Comment: `orElse()` would be the natural choice in most situations. In our code base we use `orElse()` 31 times and `orElseGet()` 0 times at all.

Comment: @OleV.V. I did the same thing just now :) one usage of `orElseGet` - the returned object comes from a database call.

Comment: That’s certainly warranted! @Eugene Thanks for that stats.

Comment: Related: [Difference between `Optional.orElse()` and `Optional.orElseGet()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think I am starting to understand your question. Execution order with `Optional` can be different from what we are used to in procedural programming (the same is true for Java streams and other code using lambdas).

I will use the two examples from [Eugene’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261755/5772882):

```
    o1.orElse(new MyObject()); // 1055e4af
```

This is plain old Java: it’s a call to `orElse()` taking `new MyObject()` as argument. So the argument is evaluated first and a new `MyObject` created. This is then passed to `orElse()`. `orElse()` looks to see whether a value is present in the `Optional`; if so it returns that value (discarding the newly created object); if not, it returns the object given to it in the argument. This was the simpler example.

```
    o1.orElseGet(() -> {
        System.out.println("Should I see this");
        return new MyObject();
    });
```

Again we have a method call with one argument, and again the argument is evaluated first. The lambda is only created and passed as a supplier. The code inside `{ }` is not executed yet (you also see no `Should I see this` in Eugene’s output). Again `orElseGet` looks to see if there is a value present in the `Optional`. If there is, the value is returned and the supplier we passed is ignored. If there isn’t, the supplier is invoked, the code inside `{ }` is executed to get the value to be returned from `orElseGet()`.

In the first case, one may say that a `MyObject` is created and wasted. In the second a `Supplier` is created and wasted. What you get in return is terse and null-pointer safe code in both cases. So very often it’s not important which one you pick. If creating the `MyObject` is costly or has unwanted side effects, you will of course want the second version where the object is only created when it is asked for, and is never wasted. Eugene in a comment mentions the case where the returned object comes from a database call. Database calls are usually time-consuming enough that you don’t want to make one for no purpose.

Comment: like! your wording is just perfect IMO. one plus

Comment: If Optional (o1) returns empty then "orElse" will also return empty ??? Like an following sample  code                                                                                                       
                         String x =null;
  Optional<String> o1 = Optional.ofNullable(x);
         o1.orElse("po");

Comment: Did you try it? Answer is no, in this case `orElse()` will return `"po"`.

Comment: Ya I tried and orElse returns output as "Optional.empty"

Comment: Weird. Sounds like you have printed the `Optional` (invoking its `toString()`), not the return string from `orElse()`.

Answer (score 14):

How about an example:

```
static class MyObject {
    public MyObject() {
        System.out.println("Creating one..." + this);
    }
}
```

And some usage:

```
  Optional<MyObject> o1 = Optional.of(new MyObject()); // 7382f612

    o1.orElse(new MyObject()); // 1055e4af 
    o1.orElseGet(() -> {
        System.out.println("Should I see this");
        return new MyObject();
    });
```

And some output:

```
 Creating one... MyObject@7382f612
 Creating one... MyObject@1055e4af
```

In case `Optional` *has a value*; `orElse` is still called but not used. On the contradictory `orElseGet` is not called.

Consider the case when creating the object is expensive; which one you will use?

It's actually easier to understand I think if you look in the code:

```
public T orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> supplier) {
    return value != null ? value : supplier.get();
}
```

Comment: Just one confusion,,, at a time orElse and orElseGet will execute?? not as per above code

Comment: Am I the sole to whom _is still called but not used_ looks like a poor API design? What is the reason to call something but not use it? Is it similar to `finally` in `try-catch` expression?

Comment: @MikeB. how is that similar? `finally` is *always* called. Also how many times have you written `new HashMap<>()` for example to only add two entries to it for example - more space is reserved, but you are not using it. And most probably `orElse(new ArrayList<>())` would be cheaper that calling a `Supplier` that produces one.

Comment: @Eugene, as far as I understand, `orElse()` is always called, no matter if the object to whom belongs `orElse()` is `null` or not `null`.

Comment: @MikeB. now I get your point, yes `orElse` is always called; not sure if this is a bad API decision though. It is sometimes cheaper to create an Object and not use it, than defer to some method that might create it - and I really think this is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget/47951385#47951385), you might want to consider the second approach when the **required resource is expensive to get**.

```
// Always get heavy resource
getResource(resourceId).orElse(getHeavyResource()); 

// Get heavy resource when required.
getResource(resourceId).orElseGet(() -> getHeavyResource())
```