# Parameter of Optional.orElse gets called even when Optional contains value

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

The below code prints:

```
should Not have called
hello world
```

Why is `orElse` getting executed even when we have an Optional that contains a value?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String o = Optional.ofNullable("world").map(str -> "hello" + str).orElse(dontCallMe());
    System.out.println(o);
}

private static String dontCallMe() {
    System.out.println("should Not have called");
    return "why god why";
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `orElse` method [looks like](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Optional.java) this:

```
public T orElse(T other) {
   return value != null ? value : other;
}
```

There isn't any complex logic here.

As with any method, it will do the following:

- Get the actual values of all parameters passed to the method (which includes calling any methods in those parameters).
- Pass those parameters to the method.
- Execute the method.

The fact that we don't *actually* care about the value of the parameter doesn't change this process (this is just the way the language has been designed, for better or worse).

---

If you're looking to not call the method in the parameter, you're probably looking for [`Optional.orElseGet`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33170109).

This:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String o = Optional.ofNullable("world").map(str -> "hello" + str)
                   .orElseGet(() -> dontCallMe());
    System.out.println(o);
}

private static String dontCallMe() {
    System.out.println("should not have called");
    return "why oh why";
}
```

Outputs only:

```
helloworld
```

The difference here is that the thing ([Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)) we're passing to the method will stay `() -> dontCallMe()`, it does not become `() -> "why oh why"` - only when you call `get` does it actually evaluate what's going on there and does `dontCallMe` actually get called.

Comment: Nice! Suggesting orElseGet for example purposes is all good but I’d like to add something more.  one should only use this method if the operation to be performed is computationally expensive otherwise resort to orElse.

Answer (score 2):

> Please, can somebody explain why `orElse` is getting executed event
>   after map will get executed for final result.

With the [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) method regardless if the wrapped value is present or not, the default object is created.

Hence when you call the function `dontCallMe()` in the [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to return the string value; *"should Not have called"* will be printed to the console.

Using [`orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) instead of [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) would provide the result you expected although you should only use this method either when the default value is computationally expensive to create or you want to be sure this is done if and only if the value is absent (empty optional) in which case it's a necessity.

As an aside, there's no need to use `Optional.ofNullable` here, the `Optional.of` method is more appropriate as the former should *only* be used if the argument can be null and the latter *only* if the argument cannot be null.

As a reading, you can check out this good post on the baeldung site.

[Guide To Java 8 Optional](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional)

Comment: point is, in `orElseGet` you are providing a `Supplier` which delegates the creation code only when needed. the other good example where this is done are loggers