# Java Optional map and filter not working as expected

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I have following code which is supposed to return orgId from modelService but not working with Optional

```
 public Long getOrgId(String someId) {
    return this.getSpecialOrgId(someId).orElse(this.getById(someId).getOrgId());
}

private Optional<Long> getSpecialOrgId(String someId) {
    return modelService.getModel(someId).map(Model::getOrgId).filter(this::isConditionTrue);
}
```

This code is not working `getSpecialOrgId` always returns `empty`

But following code works well, not sure what's wrong with above code

```
 private Long getOrgId(String someId) {
     Optional<Long> orgIdFromModel = this.getSpecialOrgId(someId);
     if (orgIdFromModel.isPresent()) {
         return orgIdFromModel.get();
     }
     return this.getById(someId).getOrgId();
 }

 private Optional<Long> getSpecialOrgId(String someId) {
     Optional<Model> modelOptional = modelService.getModel(someId);
     if (modelOptional.isPresent()) {
         Model model = modelOptional.get();
         if (isConditionTrue(model.getOrgId())) {
             return of(model.getOrgId());
         }
     }
     return empty();
 }
```

where `isConditionTrue` is always `true`, This is exact code, I have changed some variable names only

Comment: I think there is something else happening, the second method does the exact same thing, try with a debugger.

Comment: If we can’t **reproduce** it, we cannot help.... provide some sample data to prove what your saying is actually the case.

Comment: suggestion : You *may* replace `return this.getSpecialOrgId(someId).orElse(this.getById(someId).getOrgId())` with `return this.getSpecialOrgId(someId).orElseGet(() -> this.getById(someId).getOrgId());`

Comment: Aha! I got it now thanks, It's because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget

Comment: @dsk you mean you had a side effect in the get?

Comment: `.orElse(this.getById(someId).getOrgId());` was getting called even before `getSpecialOrgId` which used to throw exception. I misunderstood that method, should have used `orElseGet` instead

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should replace your `orElse` in `getOrgId` by `orElseGet(() -> getById(someId).getOrgId())`.