# When to use Optional.orElse() rather than Optional.orElseGet()

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I've read the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget) about the difference between `Optional.orElse()` and `Optional.orElseGet()`.

It seems that `orElseGet()` is always more efficient than `orElse()` because of lazy evaluation, and it's apparently visible even when benchmarking very simple examples like this one (see part 4): https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional-or-else-vs-or-else-get

So, are there any use cases where it's better to use `orElse` rather than `orElseGet`?

Comment: maybe if the chances that the Optional is empty is higher.

Comment: Like the link says: _"by default, it makes more sense to use orElseGet() every time **unless the default object is already constructed and accessible directly.**"_

Comment: It makes sense when you've already endured the cost of creating an object. Otherwise, you can delay object creation until it's actually required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. In most cases, you type less when using `orElse`, since it is shorter than `orElseGet` and, compare the signatures of them:

---

```
orElse(T other)
orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> other)
```

a `Supplier<? extends T> other` is most likely longer than `T other`. If the performance is not so critical you may choose to type less.  Programmer's effort also counts  :-) For example, compare:

```
orElseGet(() -> 1)
orElse(1)
```

2. As your link has mentioned:

> by default, it makes more sense to use orElseGet() every time unless
>   **the default object is already constructed** and accessible directly.

Comment: The first part doesn't really answer the question, other than to say "it's less verbose", which isn't a great reason. The 2nd part is the key.

Answer (score 3):

One of the major use cases where it could be preferable would be when you know you need to fall back to a constant (or even an object already created) to default to. I mean, just compare how poor could this be :

```
int first = Stream.of(1,3,5).filter(i->i%2==0).findFirst().orElseGet(new Supplier<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        return 1;
    }
});
```

or its lambda representation

```
int first = Stream.of(1,3,5).filter(i->i%2==0).findFirst().orElseGet(() -> 1);
```

which is redundant as compared to

```
int first = Stream.of(1,3,5).filter(i->i%2==0).findFirst().orElse(1);
```

Comment: The first sentence is the key to the right answer for the actual question of "when to use" it (I think the lambda stuff gets in the way). If you have a constant or already-created object that you want to use when the optional is empty, then the .orElse() is the right way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the short answer, for a more detailed answer, please check out [my stackoverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget/47951385#47951385)

- **orElse()** will always call the given function whether you want it or not, regardless of `Optional.isPresent()` value
- **orElseGet()** will only call the given function when the `Optional.isPresent() == false`

And as the first approach will always get the resource, you might want to consider the second approach when the required resource is **expensive to get**.

Comment: so why not flagging as duplicate?