# Java Optional working of orElse is not as if else

Tags: java

In Optional while optional.orElse method is call, irrespective of the element is present or not the orElse part is executed it does not behave as the if else condition.

In the below code if you see in **Case 1** both getNullPoJo and getDefaultPoJo is executed since getNullPoJo will return empty Optional

In **Case 2** where you will get a Optional with loaded value (from getLoadedPoJo) also you getDefaultPoJo is executed

I am just trying to understand the working of optional.orElse.

```
public static void main (String [] a) {
    PoJo poJo1=getNullPoJo().orElse(getDefaultPoJo());//Case 1
    System.out.println("pojo1 Got "+poJo1.getVariable());
    PoJo poJo2=getLoadedPoJo().orElse(getDefaultPoJo());//Case 2
    System.out.println("pojo2 Got "+poJo2.getVariable());
}

private static Optional<PoJo> getNullPoJo() {
    System.out.println("Executing getNullPoJo");
    Optional<PoJo> optional=Optional.empty();
    return optional;
}

private static Optional<PoJo> getLoadedPoJo() {
    System.out.println("Executing getLoadedPoJo");
    PoJo poJo =new PoJo();
    poJo.setVariable("Loaded");
    Optional<PoJo> optional=Optional.of(poJo);
    return optional;
}

private static PoJo getDefaultPoJo() {
    System.out.println("Executing getDefaultPoJo");
    PoJo poJo =new PoJo();
    poJo.setVariable("Default");
    return poJo;
}
```

**The current Output is:**

> Executing getNullPoJo
>
> Executing getDefaultPoJo
>
> pojo1 Got Default
>
> Executing getLoadedPoJo
>
> Executing getDefaultPoJo
>
> pojo2 Got Loaded

**My Expected Output is:**

> Executing getNullPoJo
>
> Executing getDefaultPoJo
>
> pojo1 Got Default
>
> Executing getLoadedPoJo
>
> pojo2 Got Loaded

I do not want the call to getDefaultPoJo in **Case 2**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \`Optional.orElse()\` and \`Optional.orElseGet()\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget)

Comment: @manish Though it may be reasonable to use `orElseGet` here, the question isn't about it: OP's confusion comes from a faulty analogy between the method `Optional#orElse` and the control flow statement `if-else`. We shouldn't close it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `orElseGet()` to avoid evaluating `getDefaultPoJo()` when the `Optional` is not empty:

```
PoJo poJo1=getNullPoJo().orElseGet(() -> getDefaultPoJo());
PoJo poJo2=getLoadedPoJo().orElseGet(() -> getDefaultPoJo());
```

Comment: Why can't you `orElseGet(getDefaultPoJo)`?

Comment: @Caleth it just makes no sense if `getDefaultPoJo` refers to the method... Did you mean a method reference `orElseGet(ClassWhereTheMethodDefined::getDefaultPoJo)`?

Answer (score 15):

```
getNullPoJo().orElse(getDefaultPoJo());
```

It's a method chain, and every method in this chain will get executed, no matter how the underlying API is supposed to work.

```
1) getNullPoJo()
2) r = getDefaultPoJo()
3) orElse(r)
```

In order to execute a method, its actual parameters must be evaluated. To call `orElse(getDefaultPoJo())`, `getDefaultPoJo()` must be invoked as well. That's the reason you are getting more than you expected.

Usually, you will see

```
.orElse(null);
.orElse(defaultValue);
```

where `null`, and `defaultValue` are predefined values that don't require any calculations.

On the other hand, we write

```
.orElseGet(() -> generateDefaultValue());
.orElseGet(() -> calculateDefaultOutcome());
```

where `generateDefaultValue` and `calculateDefaultOutcome` are methods that do perform some calculations (intensive ones or ones we don't want to execute until the right moment [your case]).

Compare,

```
.orElseGet(() -> createDefaultPoJo());
.orElse(DEFAULT_POJO);
```

where `DEFAULT_POJO` is a variable initialised prior to this method call, and `createDefaultPoJo()` is a method that creates a default instance every time it gets called.

Answer (score 5):

The output is correct, `Optional.orElse()` will allways execute the else-action. (the expression you provide) Use `orElseGet()` -which only calls the function if `Optional.isPresent == false`- for your desired output:

[Difference between `Optional.orElse()` and `Optional.orElseGet()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-