# How to write "if optional is empty, call next method returning optional, if not return this non-empty optional" several times in a functional style?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, option-type

Assume I have this method

```
public Optional<String> validateAndReturnErrorMessage(SomeEcommerceSale s) {
    Optional<String> errorWithItem = validateItem(s.getItem());
    if (errorWithItem.isPresent()) return errorWithItem;

    Optional<String> errorWithPayment = validatePayment(s.getPayment());
    if (errorWithPayment.isPresent()) return errorWithPayment;
    
    // assume I have several other cases like the 2 above

    return Optional.empty(); // meaning there were no errors
```

My problem is, since [`OrElse and OrElseGet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget) return `<T>` and not `Optional<T>`, is there a native way to do rewrite this into a more functional way without having several loosely coupled return statements?

**EDIT**

I would like to check validations one by one, since they are external and heavy. This way, I would call only the necessary ones

Comment: You could technically make an Optional<Optional<T>>, but I’m not sure that would scale up nicely....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This kind of situation is what [`Optional.or`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) was added for. It was added in Java 9, so if you're still on Java 8 then you can't use it.

```
return validateItem(s.getItem())
    .or(() -> validatePayment(req.getPayment()))
    .or(() -> /*another one*/);
```

If you are stuck on Java 8, you could write a helper method

```
public static <T> Optional<T> firstNonEmpty(List<Supplier<Optional<T>>> supplierList) {
    for (Supplier<Optional<T>> supplier : supplierList) {
        Optional<T> value = supplier.get();
        if (value.isPresent()) return value;
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

And it use it like so:

```
return firstNonEmpty(
    Arrays.asList(
        () -> validateItem(s.getItem()),
        () -> validatePayment(req.getPayment()),
        () -> /*another one*/
    )
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`or`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)):

> If a value is present, returns an `Optional` describing the value, otherwise returns an `Optional` produced by the supplying function.

```
return validatePayment(s.getItem()).or(() -> validatePayment(s.getPayment()));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a long/dynamic list of items to validate, you may want to use a stream:

```
return Stream.<Supplier<String>>of(s::getItem, req::getPayment, ...)
         .map(s -> this.validateItem(s.get()))
         .filter(Predicate.not(Optional::isEmpty)) //or filter(o -> !o.isEmpty())
         .findFirst();
```

Comment: on `.map(s -> this.validateItem(s.get()))` I would have to process a validation before checking if the previous one failed, this would not suit my needs, since these validations are external and heavy :(

Comment: @rado no. `findFirst()` is short-circuiting. So if the first element passes all validation, it will be returned and the second one won't even be validated.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, this suit my needs